# How to Disable JqueryUI Accordian Section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Hi guys I'm trying to disable queryUI section ,I have only two section , so far I have tried some of my hacks but none seems to work ,

Here what I have tried so far,

```
        //Enable section1 by remove attributes
        $('#subfacEdit').removeAttr("disabled");//div
        $('#subfacEdit').removeAttr("display");//div
        $('#HeadersubfacEdit').removeAttr("disabled");//H3
        $('#HeadersubfacEdit').removeAttr("display");//H3

        //Disable section2
        $('#facEdit').attr("disabled", "disabled");//div
        $('#facEdit').attr("display", "none");//div
        $('#HeaderfacEdit').attr("disabled", "disabled");//H3
        $('#HeaderfacEdit').attr("display", "none");//H3

        $('#editAccdordian').accordion("activate", 1);//activate section2
```

**Analysis:**
Div does becomes disabled but I guess *display attributes is not applied*,I only want make sections unclickable by any means.

**I have tried MasterMinds Solution with little change ?**
http://jsfiddle.net/X8MFf/15/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this will work for you...

```
$(".DISABLE").click(function(){
      $(this).next().hide();
      $("#accordion").accordion({active:current});
  });
```

> [Complete Example](http://jsfiddle.net/master_smind/X8MFf/10/)

```
...
//JAVASCRIPT
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $accordion = $("#accordion").accordion({ collapsible: true });
  $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "clearStyle", true );

  var current=null;

  $("#accordion h3:not(.DISABLE)").click(function(){
    current = $accordion.accordion("option","active");       
  });

  $(".DISABLE").click(function(){
      $(this).next().hide();
      $("#accordion").accordion({active:current});
  });
});
...  
  //HTML
  <div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
    <div>
        MUK - 1
    </div>
    <h3 **class="DISABLE"**><a href="#">Section 2 (Disabled)</a></h3>
    <div>
        MUK - 2
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
    <div>
        MUK - 3
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section 4</a></h3>
    <div>
        MUK - 4
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working somewhat , onclicking disable section ,last time opened section is opened.

Comment: on clicking disabled section there shud be No Action ,or in other word click should be wasted.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a special `data-` attribute to the ones you want to disable, say `data-enabled="false"`. Then, using the `beforeActivate` event, prevent from switching. Something along the lines of

```
$( "#EditAccdordian" ).on( "accordionbeforeactivate", function( event, ui ) {
  if( ui.newHeader && ui.newHeader.attr('data-enabled') == 'false') {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
} );
```

You can also bind the event in the accordion creation.

```
$( "#EditAccdordian" ).accordion({
  beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
    if( ui.newHeader && ui.newHeader.attr('data-enabled') == 'false') {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
```

Your disabled header should now look like:

```
<h3 id="HeaderfacEdit" data-enabled="false">Header content</h3>
```

**EDIT:**
I removed the jquery selection of ui.newHeader because it is a jquery object. Validation of the object should be done as it is empty when collapsing (see [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-beforeActivate)).

Comment: hmm , beforeActivate event will check for the attribute value and based on that will proceed for activation or will leave the activation of accordian ?

Comment: so I would just have to data-enabled="false" or data-enabled="true" by .js rest will taken care by the beforeActivate event ?

Comment: @dotNetSoldier Exactly. The `event.preventDefault()` prevents the accordion to change. You can then set/change the value with `$('#HeaderfacEdit').attr('data-enabled', 'true')`. If you replace `data-enabled` by a class, you can even style the disabled accordions differently.

Comment: It didn't work for me ,I used my same technique with some twist